# MACOS | When I click on the "a" tag in the Swiper Slider it does not go to the page

Tags: javascript, html, css, swiper.js

When I click on the "a" tag in the swiper slider, it does not go to the page and the slider starts to slide

this problem happens on mac

``

```
<div class="swiper-wrapper">
     <?php do { ?>
  <div class="swiper-slide">
    <div class="slider-left-box">
       <a href="<?php echo $SiteURL ?>tur-bilgisi/<?php echo $row_rsOneCikan['Seo']; ?>" title="<?php echo $row_rsOneCikan['Baslik']; ?>">
  <img src="<?php echo $SiteURL ?>images/turlar/<?php echo $row_rsOneCikan['ResimBuyuk']; ?>" alt="<?php echo $row_rsOneCikan['Baslik']; ?>">
  <div class="slider-left-box-content">
    <div class="slider-left-box-content-wrapper">
      <h3>ÖNE ÇIKAN TURLAR<span>yeni</span></h3>
      <h4><?php echo $row_rsOneCikan['Baslik']; ?></h4>
      <ul>
        <li>
         
            <h5><?php echo $row_rsOneCikan['KisaBilgi']; ?> </h5>
          
        </li>
        
      </ul>
      <span style="color:#fff">Rezervasyon Yap</span> <img src="<?php echo $SiteURL ?>images/view-icone.png" alt="Rezervasyon Yap">
    </div>
    </div>
    </a>
  </div>
  </div>
 <?php } while ($row_rsOneCikan = mysql_fetch_assoc($rsOneCikan)); ?>
</div>

<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>


<div class="swiper-button-prev"><i class="fa fa-angle-left"></i></div>
<div class="swiper-button-next"><i class="fa fa-angle-right"></i></div>
```

```

Comment: please put your html tags

Comment: I added my html tags, but this problem exists on every site in MACOS generally.

Comment: dude, why you remove your javascript code XD please put both of them

Comment: The above system did not allow. i added it here

Comment: var mySwiper = new Swiper('.swiper-home', {
   loop: true,
              slidesPerView: 1,
  autoplay: {
        delay: 2500,
        disableOnInteraction: false,
      },
      watchSlidesProgress: true,
    observer: true,
observeParents: true,
  
    pagination: {
        el: '.swiper-home .swiper-pagination',
        clickable: true,
      },

    navigation: {
      nextEl: '.swiper-home .swiper-button-next',
      prevEl: '.swiper-home .swiper-button-prev',
    },
  });